# Yahoo Maps Setting Smartwindow Dimensions

Tags: javascript, yahoo, yahoo-maps, yahoo-api

I am looking to be able to change the dimensions of smartwindows I have set to appear whenever a given marker is clicked.  The default sizing mechanism is not producing windows that are wide enough.  Checked the [Yahoo Maps API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/V3.8/index.html) but couldnt find any way to pass dimensions to a smart window.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldnt find any solution that would pass parameters to the smartwindow function, but in any case i managed a workaround by setting CSS styles for the html elements i was rendering inside the smart windows.  how the dimensions for a smart window are calculated without specifying dimensions for elements within the window is still unclear to me (as it did not reflect standard styling) so in any case if anyone has a more elegant solution additions are still welcome.